# How do we do bool operations without compiler warnings

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I have two `bool`s, i want to some booleans operations. (And, Or)
Example:

```
bool tellStatusOk() 
{
  bool res1 = IsRunning();  // a test funtion which returns ok/fail
  bool res2 = IsActive();
  return res1 & res2;
}
```

But the VC complains it is a lnt-logical-bitwise-mismatch [int-logical-bitwise-mismatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/lnt-logical-bitwise-mismatch?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(lnt-logical-bitwise-mismatch)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170).
I don't want do use && as supposed. Because it make no sense for me for booleans data  type.

Comment: *"I don't want do use `&&` as supposed. Because it make no sense for me..."* **It makes perfect sense**.

Comment: [Turn of the warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/cpp-linter-overview?view=msvc-170#configure-the-linter) as described in the page linked from the page you linked?

Comment: Why does `&&` make no sense?  You are doing a logical operation and `&&` is logical and.

Comment: _"I don't want do use && ... it make no sense for me"_ You may need to find a way for it to make sense for you.  `&&` is very appropriate for boolean contexts.  You seem to know the answer to your question, and you are telling us you don't want it.

Comment: To paraphrase: *"Because [using a boolean operator] make no sense for me for booleans data type."* Why does using a bit-wise operator (`&`) for boolean types make more sense to you than using a boolean operator (`&&`)?

Comment: You've got it backwards - ignoring overloads, `&&` makes more sense for booleans (its result is `bool`), and `&` makes more sense for non-booleans (its result is a suitable promotion of the operands' types, but never `bool`).

Comment: You can use the `&` and eliminate the warning by doing this: `return static_cast<bool>(static_cast<int>(res1) & static_cast<int>(res2));`  Ezpz.

Comment: My view: && converts bool to int. That is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Thanks all folks! I was confused and have mixed & and &&. I come from mathematics algebra. And there is only a letter for AND / OR. Ex A^B , A v B.

Comment: @TomTom *"My view: && converts bool to int"* -- First, this would have been good information to include in your question, so that people understand where you are comin from. Second, your view is wrong. In fact, `&&` converts `int` to `bool`; see [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical#Explanation). *Trust your compiler's warnings. Especially when you have tried to import knowledge from another subject. Your compiler knows the C++ specs better than most people.*

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want do use && as supposed. Because **it make no sense** for me for booleans data type.

It (using `&&`) makes perfect sense to me.

> How do we do bool operations without compiler warnings

Just use `&&` instead of `&`.

Answer (score 2):

Without appropriate `&&`, you might do:

```
bool tellStatusOk() 
{
    bool res1 = IsRunning();
    bool res2 = IsActive();
    return (static_cast<int>(res1) & static_cast<int>(res2)) != 0;
}
```

but, following seems fine

```
bool tellStatusOk() 
{
    return IsRunning() && IsActive();
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the `&&` operator is a short circuit operator, that does not evaluate the second operand if the first one is already false. This might or might not be what the OP want.